# Python To JS Using JSON objects, decoding issue

Tags: javascript, python, json, bottle

I am currently working on a python bottle app and have built an array like the one below in Python.

```
[{'text': 'aampm', 'size': 1}, {'text': 'absolutely', 'size': 1},...
```

I added this to a json object using json.dumps() and then trying to pass the value to the front end using template like the following:

```
return template('example',
                word_cloud = word_cloud)
```

Within the javascript area, I load the file using the following:

```
var cloud = JSON.parse({{word_cloud}});
```

But I am getting an issue because it is returning the list like this and replace the "'" with """.

```
var cloud = JSON.parse([{&quot;text&quot;: &quot;aampm&quot;, &quot;size&quot;: 1}, {&quot;text&quot;
```

How do I make it so that it loads in the right format -

```
([{'text': 'word', 'size': 5}, {'text': 'cloud', 'size': 15}])
```

Comment: Is the statement `var cloud = JSON.parse({{word_cloud}});` being rendered as part of a Jinja2 template?  If so you may need to filter it using the [`safe`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#working-with-automatic-escaping) filter (i.e. `{{ word_cloud | safe }}`).

Comment: That's not "the right format". JSON uses doble quotes as string delimiters.

Comment: I am trying to build a word cloud and it needs the input to be in the format in the third code set - ([{'text': 'word', 'size': 5}, {'text': 'cloud', 'size': 15}]). I am making a bottle app and passing to the javascript section using {{value}}. I tried the {{word_cloud | safe}} and still getting the following - var cloud = JSON.parse([{&quot;size&quot;: 1, &quot;text&quot;: &quot;aampm&quot;}, {&quot;size&quot;: 1,...

Comment: I have added the project to GitHub. It might make it a little easier to show what I am doing and the issue I am facing. https://github.com/RyanKramer/TwitterAnalytics

Comment: specifically, it would be in /html/example.html and the code that returns the template would be on lines 271 and 272 in TwitterAnalytics.py

Answer (score 0):

let's rewrite your code in
**views.py**

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def your_function(request):
    result = [{'text': 'aampm', 'size': 1}, {'text': 'absolutely', 'size': 1},...
    return JsonResponse(result, safe = False, status = 200)
```

This will give you your expected response.

Comment: This is a bottle app. I am not sure if this will work unless recreate the app as a django app.

Comment: then I completely missed it. Anyway If you recreate it in Django you can use this.

Comment: Thanks. As a last resort I may do this but for now, I think it would be an easy fix once I find the actual fix :). I added GitHub details above if you want to see what I am doing specifically.